# Does $wpdb->get_row() add LIMIT 1 to the query?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been trying to investigate either $wpdb->get_row() adds a LIMIT 1 dynamically to the executed query, since it only returns 1 row. But couldn't find the LIMIT added anywhere in the code.

Does that mean that $wpdb->get_row()  does not add LIMIT 1 dynamically to the query? If so, shouldn't it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. It just executes the query it's given and returns the first row from the results.

Comment: @ceejayoz Shouldn't it add it dynamically? I've been relying on it thinking it adds it, until I started getting performance issues.

Comment: Again, I don't think it does. The WordPress database class is kinda 2000s-y.